# How to convert hierarchical dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tree

I want get an hierarchical data like

```
delhi = 10 vehicle
1 vehicle = 1 battery
1 battery = 4 packs
 a pack = 2 modules 
1 module = 104 cells
```

in pandas dataframe

here is an example of  heirarchical dictionary which i want to convert to a datframe shown in image

[![datframe which i want to get converted from dictionary][1]][1]

```
tempdict = {
    'vehicle1':[
        {'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, 
        {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, 
        {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, 
        {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}
    ]
}
```

here is the whole dictionary that i want to convert

```
listone = ['pack' ]
listtwo = ["{0}".format(i) for i in range(1,105)]
pack104 = list(''.join(e) for e in itertools.product(listone, listtwo))
dict = {'delhi': [{'vehicle1':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle2':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle3':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]},{ 'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle4':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle5':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle6':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle7':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle8':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle9':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]},
 {'vehicle10':[{'pack1':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack2':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack3':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}, {'pack4':[{'module1':pack104}, {'module2':pack104}]}]}]}

'''





[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mcoJ.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop And the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'vehicle': k, 'pack': k2, 'module': next(iter(d2))}
                   for k, l in tempdict.items() for d in l
                   for k2, l2 in d.items() for d2 in l2])
```

Output:

```
    vehicle   pack   module
0  vehicle1  pack1  module1
1  vehicle1  pack1  module2
2  vehicle1  pack2  module1
3  vehicle1  pack2  module2
4  vehicle1  pack3  module1
5  vehicle1  pack3  module2
6  vehicle1  pack4  module1
7  vehicle1  pack4  module2
```

Comment: I think the dictionary is supposed to be the input, not the output...

Comment: @Nick damn, thanks for telling me!

Comment: thank you it is working   i have added the whole dictionary can you help me regarding it please it will be very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the hierarchical dictionary to a Pandas dataframe:

1. Import the **Pandas** library.
2. Create a **dictionary** comprehension to create a list of dictionaries,
   where each dictionary represents a row in the dataframe.
3. Use the **DataFrame()** constructor to create a dataframe from the list of dictionaries.
4. Set the index of the dataframe to the **vehicle** column.Display the dataframe.

your py code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dictionary comprehension to create a list of dictionaries
df_list = [{
   'vehicle': key,
   'battery': value['battery'],
   'packs': value['packs'],
   'modules': value['modules'],
   'cells': value['cells']
  } for key, value in tempdict.items()]

# Create a dataframe from the list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)

# Set the index of the dataframe to the `vehicle` column
df.set_index('vehicle', inplace=True)

# Display the dataframe
df
```

Output :

```
   Vehicle  battery  packs  modules  cells
0  vehicle1     1       4       2      104
1  vehicle2     1       4       2      104
2  vehicle3     1       4       2      104
3  vehicle4     1       4       2      104
```